# Laravel MySQL join tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
    $products= DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('categoryables', 'categoryables.categoryable_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftJoin('categories', 'categoryables.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->leftJoin('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')

        ->leftJoin('colors', 'products.color_id', '=', 'colors.id')   //'products.color_id' = "1,3,5,6"

        ->whereIn('categoryables.category_id', $categories)
        ->select('products.*','categories.path', 'categories.title', 'brands.name_brand',
            DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(colors.name_color) as name_colors"),
            DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(colors.img_color) as img_colors")
        )
        ->groupBy('products.id','categories.path','categories.title')
        ->paginate(5);
```

I need to add colors to the product table.
I created two tables: products and colors.
In the product table there is a field "Color_id" with a value of "1,3,5,6" - this is a line with "id" from the color table. How to get all the goods with their colors?

Comment: Why do you use leftjoin why not relation between model

Comment: use Many To Many ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a column called color_ids consider having a relation table called something like "product_colors" which will have 2 fields "product_id" and "color_id" and then you can introduce a simple join between products and colors via that table you just join products on product_colors and also join colors on product_colors and filter by whatever you need, I think that this DB structure makes more sense and is more normalized and easier to use in classic sql stuff :)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  products 
JOIN product_colors ON product_colors.product_id = products.id
JOIN colors ON colors.id = product_colors.id
WHERE
  products.id = 1234;
```

Or something like this, will basically give you all of the colors for the product with the id 1234.

Hope this idea helps.